# PayPal REST API: equivalent of instant update

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

chaps,

i've found info on the 'instant update' feature in the 'express checkout' version of paypal:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECInstantUpdateAPI/

is this functionality available with the 'payments rest api'? we have the exact same thing with our basket page where a customer can pay using paypal. if they change their shipping details in paypal, we need to recalculate the shipping.

does anyone know if this is possible?

thanks for any suggestions,

jake